# Good resources for Multi-threading encryption in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, encryption

I'm writing some encryption code that will encrypt, decrypt, sign, and verify information. I want to make it so that each of the functions with run on a different thread. I've tried to find an answer to this online, but I can't find an informational article on multi threading that answers my question. Are there any articles that can explain multi threading clearly to me for my case?

My Code:

```
const cluster = require('cluster'); const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length; let events = require('events'); const crypto = require('crypto'); const readline = require('readline'); const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256'); const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa'); const { MessageChannel } = require('worker_threads'); const {Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData} = require('worker_threads');     let eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter(); let key = new NodeRSA({}); key.generateKeyPair(2048); console.log(key.isPublic(true));


function signing(message) {
    return key.sign(message, 'base64'); }

function verification(signature, message) {
    return key.verify(message, signature,"ascii","base64"); }


/*let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout   });
     rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
    // TODO: Log the answer in a database
    console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

    rl.close();   });*/ // for reading user input later let message1 = "Hi, this is just the first test"; console.log(message1); let temp = "random";

let listener1 = function() {
    console.log('listener1 executed.');
    temp = key.encrypt(message1, "base64");
    console.log(temp); }

let listener2 = function() {
    console.log('listener2 executed.');
    temp = key.decrypt(temp, "ascii");
    console.log(temp);

}

let listener3 = function() {
    console.log('listener3 executed.');
    temp = signing(temp,"base64");
    console.log(temp); }

let listener4 = function() {
    console.log('listener4 executed.');
    console.log(temp);
    temp = verification(temp, message1);
    console.log(temp); }

eventEmitter.addListener('encrypt', listener1);

eventEmitter.on('decrypt', listener2); eventEmitter.on('sign', listener3); eventEmitter.on('validate', listener4); let eventListeners
= require('events').EventEmitter.listenerCount(eventEmitter, 'decrypt'); console.log(eventListeners + " Listner(s) listening to decrypt event");

// Fire the connection event  eventEmitter.emit('encrypt');

// Fire the connection event  eventEmitter.emit('decrypt');

eventListeners = require('events').EventEmitter.listenerCount(eventEmitter, 'decrypt'); console.log(eventListeners + " Listener(s) listening to encrypt event");

eventEmitter.emit("sign"); eventListeners = require('events').EventEmitter.listenerCount(eventEmitter, 'sign'); console.log(eventListeners + " Listener(s) listening to signing event");

eventEmitter.emit("validate"); eventListeners = require('events').EventEmitter.listenerCount(eventEmitter, 'validate'); console.log(eventListeners + " Listener(s) listening to validation event");


console.log("Program Ended.");
```

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic on SO. If you have a specific problem with your code, consider re-asking the question and addressing it.

Comment: You want to do multithreading... In NodeJs?